# Две точки на плоскости заданы своими координатами. Разработайте, отладьте и проверьте программу, которая определяет какая из точек находится ближе

Tags: python

Две точки на плоскости заданы своими координатами. Разработайте, отладьте и
протестируйте программу, определяющую, которая из точек находится ближе к началу координат.

Comment: Что вам не понятно?

Answer (score 1):

1. определить длину вектора от начала координат до точки P1
2. определить длину вектора от начала координат до точки P2
3. сравнить две длины которая меньше - значит эта точка ближе к началу координат

Например.

Есть точка P(x,y,z) в 3D пространстве

или

Есть точка P(x,y) в 2D пространстве

Есть теорема Пифагора - длина вектора.

В 3D пространстве длина вектора равна len = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

В 2D пространстве длина вектора равна len = sqrt(x * x + y * y);

где sqrt - корень квадратный (из языка С++).

Comment: Где тут вектор, все величины скалярные.

Comment: Точка на плоскости не может быть скалярной величиной. Точка на плоскости определяется координатами X,Y.

Comment: Расстояние между точкой и началом координат, величина скалярная. Там нет ни какого направления.

Comment: "Длина" чего-либо пишется с одной Н. "Длинна" с двумя Н пишется, если это характеристика, например, "длинна как баржа".

Comment: Корень не нужен.

Comment: Корень не нужен если len * len = x * x + y * y - теорема Пифагора. В принципе можно сократить вычисления- без корня сделать. Вопрос был - Две точки на плоскости заданы своими координатами - а не длинами. Направление от начала координат к точке- это вектор.